# I've applied for a US visa in India. Can I get the visa sticker in my passport at the US consulate in Canada?

Tags: visas, usa, indian-citizens

I am Indian passport holder, I booked a ticket to Canada on a particular date. I also applied for the US visa. My scheduled interview is just a few days before my departure date to Canada. I am afraid that I will not get my passport before that date. After attending my interview here, can I get my visa stamped in my passport in the US consulate in Canada ?

Comment: Have you tried asking the consulate that is handling your application in India?

Comment: It matters somewhat what kind of US visa you applied for (e.g. immigrant or nonimmigrant) and what your status in Canada is. For an IV I know what you want to won't work once the NVC has assigned your case to a consulate, but I would have to research whether the same is true for an NIV.